# Heroku scheduler not working on Rails api

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, heroku, scheduler

I want to send push notifications to devices using expo. I am successfully getting expo_push_token for each device that has enabled access and I am also successfully able to make the request using Postman. Here is my Postman request: POST request to: https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send

```
{ "to": "ExponentPushToken[xxx]", "title": "yesahhhh", "body": "lkajdsljaslda" }
```

Headers include: Accept: application/json Content-type: application/json Accept encoding: gzip, deflate Host: exp.host

So, the above work as it should via postman.

However, I cannot get it to work when I run the Heroku command: heroku run rake run_job

The run_job method is referenced in my rails app in 2 places:

lib/task/scheduler.rake:

```
task :run_job => :environment do
    puts "Running Job..."
    User.run_job
    puts "done!" 
end
```

user.rb:

```
  def self.run_job
    User.all.each do |u|
      if u.expo_push_token.present?
        require 'net/http'
        require 'json'
        begin
          uri = URI('https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send')
          http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
          http.use_ssl = true

          request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, {'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'})
          request.body = {to: u.expo_push_token, title: "Prana", body: "Time to affirm and visualize"}.to_json

          response = http.request(request)
          puts "The Response: #{response.body}"
        rescue => e
          puts "failed #{e}"
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

The user successfully receives the expo_push_token, however the push notification is not received. When I run the command heroku run rake run_job this is the response I get on terminal:

```
Running rake run_job on ⬢ prana-app... up, run.7732 (Free)
Running Job...
D, [2019-07-01T19:17:31.215548 #4] DEBUG -- :   User Load (2.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
done!
```

What is missing in my ruby code thats preventing the push notifications from being received?

Comment: I'd add a `puts "#{u.id} - #{u.expo_push_token.present?}"` call as the first line in your loop, just to be sure the code is flowing through that path. Clearly the `User.all` is being called as seen in the SQL log, but it's odd that nothing else is output.

Comment: @AdamMcCrea How can I view the logs? config.log_level  = :debug. Heroku logs is saying that it's listning on tcp://0.0.0.0:22780, which i assumed would be like localhost but it doesn't seem to be a valid link. Heroku logs doesn't seem to be putting my put log either

Comment: View your logs with the Heroku CLI: `heroku logs --tail`. To reduce the noise, add the `--dyno run` option. This will only show logs from your one-off dynos (created via `heroku run ...`).

Comment: @AdamMcCrea thank you! the issue turned out to be caused by my react function that was supposed to be sending the expo_push_token back to the associated user in rails backend. The user's essentially were not getting updated.